# Uploaded image data is undefined in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am sending an image file with ajax to my Node.js server. When i want to watch the file data it shows me 'undefined'.

app.js:

```
 var express    = require("express");
 var app        = express();
 var server     = require('http').createServer(app);
 var path       = require('path');
 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

 app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
 app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'includes')));
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

 app.post('/image-upload', function(req, res){
     console.log(req.files); ////// undefined
 });

 var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
 server.listen(port);
```

html:

```
<form id="uploadimage" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="submit-stock" />
</form>
```

javascript:

```
$("#uploadimage").on('submit',(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: base_url + "/image-upload",
            type: "POST",
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false
        });
    }));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `body-parser` module only handles standard POST requests, not multipart/form-data requests as are file uploads. For handling this, you are better off using another middle-ware like [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)

Comment: Nice. now the data of the image is presented, using the 'multer' module in addition to 'body-parser' module in my app should not cause any problems?

Comment: Use it for routes that have file uploads. Use body-parser middle-ware for other forms.